# Looping a Lua table matching for a specific key then setting the value to a variable

Tags: loops, lua, lua-table

So I have a table that looks something like this:

```
local weapons = {[46]= "Megapositron", [173]= "Sunflare", [702]= "raven"}
```

I also have a variable:

```
weaponid
```

The variable `weaponid` will contain one of the keys from weapons (46,173,702)

What I can't figure out is how to check if weaponid matches one of those keys and upon weapon id matching a key I need it to assign the keys value to another variable named weaponname.

So suppose weaponid = 173 then
weaponname = 'Sunflare'

Comment: Wow, it was that easy? Thanks John and Jan! I spent hours trying to do this in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local weaponname = weapons[weaponid]
```

`weaponname` will be `nil` if the id doesn't match any of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
weaponname = weapons[weaponid] or weaponname
```

This way, the old weapon name will be kept if there is no weapon associated to the new id.

Comment: You'd probably want to use "Unknown Weapon" instead of the last weapon's name.